# .NET - Using WebClient.Download File in a One-Way WebService

Tags: .net, web-services, webclient, httpcontext, threadabortexception

I have a simple one-way web service in my C# .NET web application. I need to download an image from a given URL and save it to my server.

However, every OTHER time I call the service it works perfectly. The other times I get a "Thread was being aborted" exception on the webClient.DownloadFile line.

I've read that WebClient uses httpWebRequest which requires access to HttpContext.Current. Is this true? If so, why can it access it, literally, every other time?

I've tried adding the following lines before my call:

WebService service = new WebService();
HttpContext.Current = service.Context;

But it doesn't make a difference.

I ran the service 10 times, here are the results:

1: Success

2: Exception:   Thread was being aborted. 
   Stack Trace: at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsState.RetrieveBytes(Int32& bytesRetrieved) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)...

3: Success

4: Exception:   Thread was being aborted.
   Stack Trace: at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsState.RetrieveBytes(Int32& bytesRetrieved) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)...

5: Success

6: Exception:   Thread was being aborted.
   Stack Trace: at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsState.SetResponse(WebResponse response) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName) ...

7: Success

8: Exception:   Thread was being aborted.
   Stack Trace: at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsState.SetResponse(WebResponse response) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName) ...

9: Success

10: Exception:   Thread was being aborted.
    Stack Trace: at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsState.SetResponse(WebResponse response) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)...

Is there any way to make this work??

EDIT: In response to question regarding posting code: There is not much to post. It is all quite simple.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://nerdliness.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]      
public class FileProcessor : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay = true)]
    public void ParseFile(String urlOfFileToGrab, String destinationPath)
    {
          try
          {
               WebClient client = new WebClient();
               client.DownloadFile(urlOfFileToGrab, destinationPath);
               client.Dispose();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {  
              //Log it
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - I am NOT using Response.Redirect or Response.End ANYWHERE in my application. Does the WebClient object itself call Response.End??

Comment: Try to wrap it in a USING statement instead.

Comment: How big is the file? Your `executiontimeout` value may need to be increased from the default of 110 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, it sounds like you are not properly disposing of resources that you are creating/consuming within your webservice.  Thus, it works, then crashes (aborts the thread which disposes of everything), then it works again.

**EDIT:**

A few other things to think about/look at.  1) I have never used the one-way binding before, does this work when you don't have that set.  2)  Are you calling these too fast?  Meaning, it the download/save done by the time you call the method again?  3)  In your web.config, are your timeouts and max download sizes set large enough to allow you to download/transfer files?

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="2048000" />
</system.web>
```

That's all that I can think of, if it doesn't help, perhaps someone else has ran into this problem before.  According to Google, your about the only one :)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have now posted the code. Is there anything else I should be doing to wrap things up in there???